# Stop Azure Site WebJob

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm

I need to stop a running webjob before stopping a site.  I can stop the site in AzureRM (`Stop-AzureRmWebApp`).  I'm confused why stopping a site doesn't stop running webjobs (how are they running if the site is off)?

From reading around and looking at MS' documentation, I don't see an RM command to stop a webjob.  All of the details I see are from a year or more ago.  Has there been any update to do this through scripts?  Kudo/Portal are not options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm confused why stopping a site doesn't stop running webjobs (how are they running if the site is off)?

It is because Stopping the web site **does not** stop the scm site that runs WebJobs. You can refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46354060/disable-a-triggered-azure-webjob?rq=1) for details. It also provides a method to fully stop the website.

> Has there been any update to do this through scripts?

There is no related RM command to stop a webjob, A issue has already been submitted [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/661).

workaround: as the [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/661) above metioned, you can use the following scripts:

```
#Stop a job
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction `
    -ResourceGroup $resourceGroup `
    -ResourceType microsoft.web/sites/continuouswebjobs `
    -ResourceName $siteName/$jobName `
    -Action stop `
    -ApiVersion 2016-08-01 `
    -Force
```

It works at my side:
[image]

Comment: Does executing this command imply there's a reason to use cancellation token on a triggered job?