# how to put azure webjob on hold with out deleting it?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webapps

I am not able to find any options to put the azure webjob on hold , Currently we disable our jobs from "Task scheduler" whenever we have a deployment.
But in Azure Webjob I cannot see an option to disable.
I read from some old forums that we can only delete , then we need to publish again.

Can anybody advise on this? if we have deployed the job , to just hold for some hours or couple of days why we need to delete it?

thanks

Comment: Related question: [Disable a Triggered Azure WebJob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46354060/disable-a-triggered-azure-webjob)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the below configuration setting to your web app to disable the Webjob.

**WEBJOBS_STOPPED** - Set this setting to 1 to disable running any job (will also stop all currently running jobs).

**WEBJOBS_DISABLE_SCHEDULE** - Set this to 1 to turn off all scheduled triggering. Unlike with WEBJOBS_STOPPED, WebJobs can still be manually invoked

For more information you can refer this [github](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#configuration-settings) link .

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have been facing similar issue while trying to debug code in development environment while disabling webjob. Below are my findings:

1.Browse through your deployed App service and find for webjob in search bar

[image]

2. Once you click on check button, it will prompt you to enable or disable webjob and here you go to choose desired action

[image]